# Analysing Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, finance, python

For uni I'm doing this exercise on brownian motion, specifically geometric brownian motion. For this part of the exercise I'm required to compute certain values: sample mean, sample variance, and the quadratic variation for m = 10, 100, 1000. The output I get is posted below but I'm not quite happy with the results. The distribution of the ends is a sort of shifted normal distribution do the variance and mean being off a little seems reasonable, but the thing I'm worried about is the quadratic variation, as this should be equal to T. T is set to 5 but the QV is nothing close to that. I cant see what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me? any help is appreciated!

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats


class BMG:  #Geometric Brownian Motion
    def __init__(self, drift, variance_term, m, T):
        self.dt = T/m
        self.Z = np.random.standard_normal(m)
        self.Y = np.zeros(m+1)
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            self.Y[i] = math.e**(variance_term*math.sqrt(self.dt)*self.Z[i-1]) + drift*self.dt
        self.arr = np.ones(m+1)
        for i in range(m):
            self.arr[i+1] = self.arr[i]*self.Y[i+1]

        self.end = self.arr[-1]


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

N = 500                 #Number of BM simulations
drift = -0.1
variance_term = 0.25
m = 500                 #Number of time-steps 
T = 5                   #Time in years

ends = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):              
    bmg = BMG(drift, variance_term, m, T)
    ends[i]=bmg.end
    axs[0].plot(np.arange(0,m+1), bmg.arr)          #Plotting BM trajectories
axs[1].hist(ends, density = True, bins=int(N/5))    #Plotting distribution of end points

plt.show()



#Sample Mean
sample_mu = 0
for i in range(N):
    sample_mu += ends[i]
sample_mu = sample_mu/N
print("sample mean:  "+ str(sample_mu) + "  analytic mean:  " + str(bmg.arr[0]*math.e**(drift*T)))

#Sample Variance
sample_var = 0 
for i in range(N):
    sample_var += (ends[i] - sample_mu)**2
sample_var = sample_var/(N-1)
print("sample variance:  "+ str(sample_var) + 
"  analytic variance:  " + str( (bmg.arr[0]**2) * (math.e**(2*drift*T)) * ((math.e**(variance_term**2))-1)))

#Quadratic variation
steps = [10, 100, 1000]
for n in steps:
    bmg1 = BMG(-0.1, 0.25, n, T)
    QV = 0

    for i in range(n):
        step = bmg1.arr[i+1] - bmg1.arr[i]
        QV += step**2

    print("for m = " + str(n) +":   QV = " + str(QV))

/* Output:
sample mean:  0.6942405094555087  analytic mean:  0.6065306597126334
sample variance:  0.16157387382343052  analytic variance:  0.023726185505356632
for m = 10:   QV = 0.12398361878757773
for m = 100:   QV = 0.4954051008996326
for m = 1000:   QV = 0.10524633607091849
*/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will provide here analytic results with which one can compare a (good) simulation. The SDE of a GBM is $dX_t=\mu X_tdt+\sigma X_t dW_t,\,X_0>0$. The solution is found by applying Ito to $f(x)=\ln x$ and we find
$$\ln X_t=\underbrace{\ln X_0 + \bigg(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\bigg)t}_{:=d_t}+\sigma W_t \implies X_t=X_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}$$
Since $X_t=e^{\ln X_t}$ and $\ln X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(d_t,\sigma^2t)$ we have that $X_t$ is lognormally distributed: for $x>0$
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_t\leq x)&=P(\ln X_t \leq \ln x)=
\\&=\int_{(-\infty,\ln x]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2t}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{(y-d_t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\bigg\}dy\end{aligned}$$
So by Leibniz integral rule and the fact that the Gaussian density decays at $y\downarrow -\infty$,
$$f_{X_t}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}P(X_t\leq x)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2t}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{(\ln x-d_t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\bigg\}$$
which is not Gaussian and not a shifted Gaussian distribution. The mean and second moment are, by using the Gaussian MGF,
$$E[X_t]=X_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}E[e^{\sigma W_t}]=X_0e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}e^{\frac{\sigma^2t}{2}}=X_0e^{\mu t}$$
$$E[X_t^2]=X_0^2e^{2(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}E[e^{2\sigma W_t}]=X_0^2e^{2(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}e^{2\sigma^2 t}=X_0^2e^{2\mu t+\sigma^2 t}$$
The variance is
$$\textrm{Var}[X_t]=E[X_t^2]-E[X_t]^2=X_0^2e^{2\mu t}(e^{\sigma^2 t}-1)$$
and one can use the usual estimators for fixed $t$. Since $X_t$ is a Ito process, the quadratic variation is
$$d[X,X]_t=\sigma^2X_t^2dt\implies [X,X]_t=\sigma^2\int_{[0,t]}X_s^2ds$$
which is not the QV of a Brownian motion, which is $t$. This value can be approximated pathwise in a simulation.